# What are the relations between $\tau$ and x, $\tau$ and y?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

A reference from “introduction to calculus and analysis I” p. 349-p.350:

a curve $y=f(x),\ x=x(t),\ y=y(t),\ \alpha\leq t \leq \beta, \ a\leq x \leq b$, the length of the curve is
$$L=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sqrt{{\dot{x}}^2+{\dot{y}}^2}dt$$

If we introduce a new parameter $\tau=\chi(t)$, where $d\tau/dt>0$, our integral formula for $L$ must give the same value whether $t$ or $\tau$. This can be verified immediately from the chain rule of differentiation and the substitution law for integrals.
$$\sqrt{{\dot{x}}^2+{\dot{y}}^2} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} = \\
\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\tau} \frac{d\tau}{dt}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dy}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dy}{d\tau}\right)^2} \frac{d\tau}{dt} ;$$
hence, if $\chi(\alpha)=a,\ \chi(\beta)=b$,
$$L=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sqrt{{\dot{x}}^2+{\dot{y}}^2}dt = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dy}{d\tau}\right)^2} \frac{d\tau}{dt} dt \\
= \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dy}{d\tau}\right)^2} d\tau $$

What are the relations between $\tau$ and x, $\tau$ and y?

$$x=x(\tau)=x[\chi(t)],\ y=y(\tau)=y[\chi(t)]]$$

Is it true? What a coincidence! I’m confused about this part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed a confusing way of stating this result. Usually one would set $t = \xi(\tau)$ instead of the other way around. Then it is obvious that this is just composition. But by setting $\tau = \chi(t)$, it is less clear. And the discussion doesn't even touch on the relationships - it just takes it for granted that they are there.

So what you need to recognize is that $\chi$ here has to be invertible, so $t = \chi^{-1}(\tau)$. That is, the value of $t$ can be viewed as depending on $\tau$. So if we relabel the relationship of $x$ on $t$ as $X(t)$ and similarly for $y$, then we have

$$x = X(t) = X(\chi^{-1}(\tau))\\y = Y(t) = Y(\chi^{-1}(\tau))$$

And if you go carefully through all the chain rules this invovles, you will see that everything works out.

Comment: Thanks, please see my answer.

Comment: @August, You should use comments or edit your original question to ask for clarifications. $$\frac {dx}{dt} = \frac {dx}{d\tau}\frac {d\tau}{dt}\\\frac {dx}{d\tau} = \frac {dx}{dt}\frac {dt}{d\tau}$$What more do you want?

Comment: Thank you very much, I can’t understand this equation:$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt}$$, I don’t know how to evaluate $dx/dt$ by applying the chain rule directly, please show me more steps. PS. I know the chain rule.

Comment: That IS the chain rule. If you know the chain rule, what is it you don't understand about this? In your post, $x$ is given as a function of $t$, not $\tau$, so $\frac {dx}{dt}$ is just differentiating that function. By means of the relation $t = \chi^{-1}(\tau)$ we can then convert that function of $t$ into a function of $\tau$ by composition. Differentiating that new function gives us $\frac {dx}{d\tau}$. The chain rule relates between these two derivatives. SInce $\tau = \chi(t)$ and $t=\chi^{-1}(\tau)$, we have $\frac {d\tau}{dt} = \chi'(t)$ and $\frac {dt}{d\tau} = (\chi^{-1})'(\tau)$

Comment: Apply the chain rule to$x[\chi^{-1}(\tau)]$, we obtain the equation: $$\frac{dx}{d\tau} = \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\tau}$$, multiply both sides of equation by $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$, we obtain $dx/dt$. This explanation, is it true? The multiplication is key steps:)

Comment: Yes, because $f\circ f^{-1}$ is the identity function, which has derivative $1$, the chain rule says that $(f^{-1})' = \frac 1{f'}$ (more accurately, $\frac 1{f'\circ f^{-1}}$, but it is common to leave that part implied). Thus $\frac {dt}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt} = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much.